# Как взять в кавычки слово в Input? Python

Tags: python, input, кавычки

Всем привет! Пишу код и столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть код -

```
print("Введите никнейм")
search = input()
```

Мне нужно чтобы на выходе (в результате) текст, который был введён, отображался в кавычках. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `print(f'"{search}"')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(f'"{input("Введите никнейм: ")}"')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=input()
print('"'+i+'"') # и все проблемы...
```

Если ответ полезен отметь как принятый.